# why can't use window in vue template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i set a property in window Object for using it globally, like this:

```
window.configs.foo=true;
```

but when use it like this:

```
<v-btn v-if="window.configs.foo">go</v-btn>
```

in console, i get this error:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "window" is not defined on the instance
>   but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
>   reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
>   initializing the property.

---

**how i can use window object in vueJs template?**

Comment: You should never use global window variables in a vue application. This is because the window var can be targeted by anything, even JS code that is not part of your app. Instead, you can use `environment variables` (if the goal is to have different config settings), or you can use `VueX` (if the goal is to have all kinds of data globally available)

Comment: @Kokodoko , thank you. i understand what you said.

Comment: @Kokodoko Sure уоu can use window variables in the a Vue app. What уоu shouldn't do is include JS code that is not part of your app. Why would уоu include JS code that is not part of your app anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, Alternate is to use $root in Vue. Define `foo` at your vue instance and it will be available in all the component with `this.$root.foo`.

Here is  the official [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-root)

Hope this helps

Comment: this.$root is not defined in modal components :(

Comment: It won't be in modal as modal passes data from the dismiss event.

Answer (score 7):

Because `v-if` is intended to be used on properties of your component. You cannot `v-if` over variables in global scope, or outside your component data or properties.

What you can do, instead, if to setup a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) on your component that targets `window.configs.foo`:

```
new Vue({ // or maybe a component, this depend on how you're using it
    template: `<div>
      <v-btn v-if="showMyButton">...</v-btn>
    </div>`
    computed: {
      showMyButton() {
        return window.configs && window.configs.foo;
      }
    }
})
```

UPDATE:

If you have to reuse this in a lot of sites, there are two things that you can do:

#### Vuex

[Using vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to set the `showMyButton` as a vuex state. Then you can access it via:

`v-if="$store.state.showMyButton"`

And you can modify it via standard [vuex mutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html).

#### Mixins

Maybe for some reason you don't want to use vuex. Then a way to reuse logic across many components is [to use mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html).

```
const configAwareMixin = {
  computed: {
    showButton() {
      return window.configs.foo;
    }
  }
}

// And then in your component:

Vue.component('stuff', {
  mixins: [buttonAwareMixin],
  template: `<div><v-btn v-if="showButton"></v-btn></div>`
})
```

Comment: I have many components that need this variable. and i don't like define computed variable in every components. do you know what i should be do?

Answer (score 0):

The only easiest solution is `Vue.prototype.$window = window;` in main.js from folder `src` and use can use `window` as `$window` inside your template. Hope can help you all.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by replacing the 'vue.js' with 'vue.min.js'! I don't know why.

Comment: I believe warnings are hidden in the minified version, as it's more often used in production environments. So the issue is probably still present FYI.

Comment: @dodgewhale I didn't mean that warning. It raises an error `cannot read property 'xxx' of undefined` if you use 'vue.js'. But 'vue.min.js' works fine.