# Web API caches 2 results in the same browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, vue.js

I have a weird case.
I use chrome 75 for Mac OS.

When I push code in console some page

```
if ('caches' in window) {
  console.log(`cache is supported`)  
}else{ 
  console.log(`cache is not supported`)
}
```

as a result I see that this is supported but I have local server on 8080 from vue. When I call it there it return that cache doesn't exists.
When I export vue cli code as production still cache is not supported in window. 
Any ideas why? Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: Just a guess, may be your browser doesn't not support template literals?
try use `'` instead of `\``

Comment: nope, I also tried such solution. The most weird is that in one tab supported on other not

Comment: Maybe this is the answer?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55323010/why-cant-use-window-in-vue-template